# I want a single button to do double command one command will terminate my present window and another command will open a new window in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def newwindow():
   -----------

def exit():
  exit()


root=Tk()
signup=Button(root,text="Sign Up",command=[ newwindow(),exitt() ],
              width=12,bg='green',fg='white',font=("arial",12,'bold'))
```

Comment: You have to pass a single function as the `command=` option of your Button.  That function can call as many other functions as it wants, of course.

Comment: wil you  please elaborate it with a code example? .i am very new in python #jasonharper

Answer (score 0):

use function as command:

````py
def newwindow():
       -----------
   
    
def myexit():
    exit()

def my_command():
    newwindow()
    myexit()
    
    root=Tk()
    signup=Button(root,text="Sign Up",command=mycommand,
                  width=12,bg='green',fg='white',font=("arial",12,'bold'))```
````